# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCWebView" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

Hello friends i got this error after linking react-native-webview to my project

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCWebView" was not found in the UIManager.

    This error is located at:
        in RNCWebView (at WebView.android.js:250)
        in RCTView (at WebView.android.js:253)
        in WebView (at App.js:7)
        in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
        in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:109)
        in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:135)
        in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

And there is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{ html: '<h1>Hello world</h1>' }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

[Error Image in my android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qZzS.jpg)

Comment: Can you tell us some more about the project you want to use it in and its code? Have you checked what the lines in the files (i.e. in WebView.android.js) mentioned in the errors are saying? You could give us this code, maybe it is a start to dig in. Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

run `react-native link react-native-webview`

check: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/140

Comment: This is not needed anymore if you are using React Native 0.60+, simply `cd ios` and `pod install`, maybe restart xCode, possibly in Xcode click in the menu on Product > Clean Build Folder, and you should be good to go

Answer (score 14):

With React Native 0.60+, no need to add anything to the podfile.
Try again `cd ios && pod install`

If it doesn't help, try restarting the simulator and rebuilding the app.
Restarting Xcode is also a good idea.

You could optionally clean the build Folder in XCode
[image]

Comment: correct answer in case react-native version > 0.0.60 with autolinking

Answer (score 5):

Try these steps.

1. Delete pods folder and podfile.lock
2. npm uninstall react-native-webview
3. npm i react-native-webview
4. cd ios
5. pod install
6. (npx) react-native run-ios
7. Reset cache

Comment: I forgot the pod install bro

Comment: Don't forget to also restart the simulator and rebuild your app

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Try Add this line to your podfile :-

`pod 'react-native-webview', :path => PROJECT_PATH + 'react-native-webview'`

then go to ios folder **cd ios** and install pods **pod install**

It has resolved this problem for me.

Comment: I did run link and I think it automatically added the line to my podfile, had to only cd ios adn pod install and it finally worked 

Comment: I would not do that with React Native 0.60+. Only `cd ios` and `pod install` is enough

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you did:

1. `npx pod-install`
2. `npx react-native run-ios`

After installing the package you. need to update pods and then run the project again.

Answer (score 3):

my solution for this problem was the following:

**Android**

1 add this in your android/settings.gradle

```
include ':react-native-webview'
project(':react-native-webview').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-webview/android')
```

2 add this in your android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-webview')
    ....
```

3 in your MainApplication.java:

```
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewPackage;//add this import
....

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new RNCWebViewPackage(),//add line
          ....
```

**IOS**

1 add the following line in your ios/Podfile and then open your terminal, go to your project ios folder and run pod install

```
...
  pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'
...
```

Comment: Thanks bro... but I can't understand why it's not mentioned in the Library Itself?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before , I tried this:

`pod 'react-native-webview', :path => PROJECT_PATH + 'react-native-webview'`

Answer (score 1):

I update webView to the latest (11.18.1) and it was fixed without any additional linking steps.

Answer (score 0):

I have done below steps:

```
 1. cd ios
 2. rm Podfile.lock
 3. pod install
```

This installed the missing library i.e. **react-native-webview** and added below line to Podfile file.

```
 pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'
```

environment which I am working on:

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5"
```

Comment: Don't modify the Podfile if you are using React Native 0.60+. There is now autolinking.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these simple steps worked for me:

1. Rebuild the App. Run:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

2. Run:

```
react-native link react-native-webview
```

3. Check if `RNCWebViewPackage` is imported in `MainApplication.java` file, which looks something like this:

```
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewPackage;
```

Note: I'm using `react-native@0.64.2`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add anything or use the link for React Native 0.60+.
In my case, which was android, I simply build the project again using:
$ npm run android

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to link manually?

Go to ../node_modules/react-native-webview/ios and drag and drop the RNCWebView.xcodeproj to Libraries folder on Xcode, right after, Go to Build Phases tab (on Xcode) in the section "Link binary With libraries" add the libRNCWebView.a (inside Libraries/RNCWebView.xcodeproj/Products). Try to build and run

Comment: Thanks bro, but this project was for andoird,  and solved by npm link, thanks lot for support bro

Answer (score 0):

I was using expo and pnpm and after install react-native-webview@11.17.2 and react-native-youtube-iframe@2.3.0 i got this error.

For me on ios emulator, remove app manually and run pnpm expo run:ios and solved

Edit:
For apk android yout have to add this on gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `react-native-webview` is a dependency of a package I installed (https://github.com/imnapo/react-native-cn-quill), but I didn't directly install `react-native-webview` itself. Cleaning the build and pod cache etc. didn't work.

After I ran `npm i react-native-webview` to explicitly install it, and then `cd ios; pod install` again, this error finally went away.

Answer (score -1):

try to re-build your project after installation and link of webview package (npx react-native run-android)

Comment: I already fixed that issue, thanks for the support bro.