# working on an android project getting RNCWebView was not found error

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-webview

I am working on a gitlab project with my friend, windows 10, I have pulled from master and there were few conflicts that I had to solve and I did `npm install` however when I run my android project by using `npx react-native start` and then from android studio I run by going to tools->AVN manager->start, my app starts loading, after a while of loading it give me this error:

```
 Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCWebView" was not found in the UIManager.
```

here is a photo:

[image]

I have already run `react-native link react-native-webview`, it didnt do anything. In my `package.json`I have this:

```
"react-native-webview": "^10.8.3",
```

here is the code:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <WebView
      ref={(ref) => setMap_ref(ref)}
      source={{html: openstreet_html}}
    />
    <LocationView address={address} navigation={navigation} />
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

I have already done everything in this [thread as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61832232/invariant-violation-requirenativecomponent-rncwebview-was-not-found-in-the-u). I get the same error. Before I pull from master this problem didnt exist. is there anything I have to do?

Comment: Try updating the packages to latest version.  Clear the npm cache and node_module folder and try again. It could be due to some packages missing.

Comment: @Sriram I delted node_module and platform tools folders and also clear the npm cache but the problem remains the same, it takes a long time loading and then it tells me the same problem after a while.

Comment: What is the version of the react-native? Did you try upgrading the react-native?

Comment: @Sriram react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: n/a - not inside a React Native project directory,

Comment: @Sriram how can I upgrade?

Comment: Could you please provide the content of package.json. Based on that I can modify the json file for your use or I can suggest you the method to upgrade.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221942/discussion-between-sriram-and-s-n).

Answer (score 0):

```
gradlew --stop
```

then Clear the project, and run again with:

```
react-native run-android --port=8082
```

this worked for me thanks to @Sriram.

Answer (score 0):

some time react-native link not link the library . try manually link the webview. you can follow these steps to link the webview to android.
https://engineering.brigad.co/demystifying-react-native-modules-linking-964399ec731b